# Bash error message on a mac using Perl

Tags: bash, perl, macintosh

I'm trying to run basic functions on Perl (Mac) but I get the same error message all the time. I managed to run programs like the simple 'hello, world' example. They work fine:

```
$ perl -w hello.pl
Hello World
```

But when I try different things, such as assigning a value to a variable, it gives me a message such as:

```
$number = 13*2;
-bash: =: command not found
```

Commands such as list seem to work, but I get the bash error all the time. I read that it can be related to the path but not sure how to exactly verify this and what's the bash doing here.

Comment: Should we understand that you entered `number = 13*2;` to the `bash` prompt? If yes, remove the spaces around the `=` sign.

Comment: I added it to the new-host:~ prompt I get in the shell. The error I get it on the bash: -bash: =13*2: command not found

Comment: Just a moment. In you second quoted command the `$` symbolizes the `bash` prompt or you typed it literally? If the later, then `bash` expanded it to nothing then tried to execute the resulted command: `=13*2`. You can not just mix `bash` and `perl` syntax like that.

Comment: new-host:~ jose$ perl -w hello.pl
Hello World
new-host:~ jose$ #this is what i obtain running the 'hello.pl' program. I'm only trying to use perl; not sure I understand why is it mixing it with bash (not intended at all). I understood that the $ sign is used for assigning values to variables in perl. The bash prompt appears with the error.

Comment: These are my permissions: crw--w----  #could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be confusing bash with perl.  The default shell on your mac is bash, which cannot set variables in the same way, or using the same syntax, as perl.  To set a variable called '$number' to the result of '13 * 2' using perl, on a bash CLI, you would:

```
my-macbook:~ $ perl -e '$number = 13 * 2; print $number, "\n";'
26
```

To do the same thing in bash itself, you could:

```
my-macbook:~ $ number=$(expr 13 \* 2); echo $number
26
```

You can't put raw perl syntax into your bash shell in Terminal, because the bash shell running in Terminal is expecting bash syntax.   Bash is a whole language unto itself, and is not compatible with perl.   To tell bash that you want to execute some code using perl instead of bash, you use Perl's `-e` flag (as in e for execute), then wrap your perl code in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I finally understood the way it works and what I was doing wrong; now I moved on significantly.

Comment: Hi Jose -- if this response helped you resolve your question, don't forget to approve the answer (with the checkmark under the voting arrows)

Answer (score 3):

To do basic arithmetic in `bash` (the shell running inside your terminal emulator) you would use one of the following constructs. The `$` prefix is used with variables in `bash` when getting the value of the variables, not in their assignment:

```
my_product=$(( 13 * 2 ))
my_product=$[ 13 * 2 ]
echo $my_product
```

As already stated `perl` is not `bash` so you have to make sure to use the right syntax with the right language.